# How to use LMS & EMP-API in the same LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, empapi, lightning-message-service

As both empApi and LMS require the import of the subscribe and unsubscribe methods. How can you use both within the same component?

```
import { subscribe, unsubscribe} from 'lightning/empApi';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe} from 'lightning/messageService';
```

This returns the following error:

```
Identifier 'subscribe' has already been declared
```

This seems like a big oversight in the LMS development.

Is the only way around this to use a child component that just listens for the LMS then bubbles the details back up?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the approach could be to use aliases in order distinguish between different modules as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

For example:

```
import { subscribe as empSubscribe, unsubscribe as empUnsubscribe} from 'lightning/empApi';
import { subscribe , unsubscribe} from 'lightning/messageService';
```